# Pandas - split dataframe on one axis and concatenate them back on another axis

Tags: pandas

How do I get a dataframe whose columns names always end in either 1 or 2, like so:

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2
1  2  4  2  3  2   5  3  2  0  3  1
2  4  3  5  3  2   2  3  2  2  4  1
3  2  5  2  6  7   3  5  3  2  5  1
```

Split it into two sets based on the last character being 1 or 2, and concatenate them back, keeping only characters prior to 1 or 2, like so:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F 
1  2  4  2  3  2   
2  4  3  5  3  2   
3  2  5  2  6  7   
5  3  2  0  3  1
2  3  2  2  4  1
3  5  3  2  5  1
```

---

**Note**: A, B, C, D, E, F are just simplified examples. actual columns names have many more characters up to 1 and 2, like 'column_a1', 'another_column2' etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for columns names passed to `stubnames` parameter:

```
a = df.columns.str.extract('(\D+)', expand=False).unique()
df = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),stubnames=a,i='index', j='tmp').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  2  4  2  3  2
1  2  4  3  5  3  2
2  3  2  5  2  6  7
3  5  3  2  0  3  1
4  2  3  2  2  4  1
5  3  5  3  2  5  1
```

Or use [`MultiIndex.from_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html) for `MultiIndex in columns` and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.columns.str.extract('(\D+)(\d+)', expand=True))
df = df.stack().rename(index=int, level=1).sort_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
0  A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  2  4  2  3  2
1  2  4  3  5  3  2
2  3  2  5  2  6  7
3  5  3  2  0  3  1
4  2  3  2  2  4  1
5  3  5  3  2  5  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this one-liner:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({idx: pd.Series(val.to_numpy().ravel()) for idx, val in df.groupby(lambda x: x[0], axis=1)})
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  2  4  2  3  2
1  5  3  2  0  3  1
2  2  4  3  5  3  2
3  2  3  2  2  4  1
4  3  2  5  2  6  7
5  3  5  3  2  5  1
>>>
```

Or use `df.melt` with `pivot`:

```
>>> x = df.melt()
>>> x['variable'] = x['variable'].str[0]
>>> x.assign(count=x.groupby('variable').cumcount()).pivot('count', 'variable', 'value').rename_axis(columns=None, index=None)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  2  4  2  3  2
1  2  4  3  5  3  2
2  3  2  5  2  6  7
3  5  3  2  0  3  1
4  2  3  2  2  4  1
5  3  5  3  2  5  1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to reshape the data :

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df.pivot_longer(names_to= '.value', names_pattern=r'(.).')

   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  2  4  2  3  2
1  2  4  3  5  3  2
2  3  2  5  2  6  7
3  5  3  2  0  3  1
4  2  3  2  2  4  1
5  3  5  3  2  5  1
```

Alternatively, you can get faster speed, depending on your data size, if you work solely in numpy; your data seems ordered (A -> F), with equal numbers:

```
new_columns = df.columns.str[0].unique()
length = new_columns.size
 reshaped = np.reshape(df.to_numpy(), (-1, length))

pd.DataFrame(reshaped, columns = new_columns)

   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  2  4  2  3  2
1  5  3  2  0  3  1
2  2  4  3  5  3  2
3  2  3  2  2  4  1
4  3  2  5  2  6  7
5  3  5  3  2  5  1
```